# Facebook sharer link works with user but not with fanpage admin

Tags: javascript, facebook, hyperlink, share

I would like to share via the facebook sharer link on image click on my website.

Here is the function I currently use :

```
function shareFacebook()
{
    // Parameters
    var title       = "Test";
    var url         = "http://test.creabox.biz/Crash%20tests/Facebook%20sharer/";
    var description = "Test de partage sur page fan...";
    var image0      = "http://images.forum-auto.com/mesimages/676992/camion-tire-par-un-boeuf1213352668.1216465659.jpg";

    // Encode complete URI
    var completeURL = encodeURI("http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?s=100&p"+
        "[title]="+title+"&p"+
        "[url]="+url+"&p"+
        "[images][0]="+image0+"&p"+
        "[summary]="+description);

    // Facebook popup
    window.open(completeURL, "sharer", "menubar=1, resizable=1, width=640, height=350");

    // Debug
    console.log(new Date(), completeURL);
    document.getElementById('debugDiv').innerHTML = completeURL;

    return false;
}
```

With this function, I can share on my wall using my everyday user, but when I'm connected through my fanpage, I cannot share anything. The popup appears but when I validate, the button goes to grey and goes back to normal after a couple of seconds.

To illustrate my problem, I have created a page wich you can see sources at :
http://test.creabox.biz/Crash%20tests/Facebook%20sharer/

Thanks in advance for your help.
Best regards

Comment: You really shouldn't use sharer.php anymore; it's been deprecated by FB.  The modern way to do this is to pop a [Feed Dialog](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Comment: Okay, I tried and I'm little confused. I have created an app to get an app_id, but I don't see why these has to be done to share a simple link. Anyway, I did this and it seems to work, but not if I'm logged as a fanpage admin. The popup tells me to log in as a user... This is the same problem with the sharer link. Sources can be found to the same previous URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the meta tags `og:image,og:title,og:description`.

Include them in page and use `sharer.php` with `u` & `t` option. Or better yet, use with `u` option only as that contains URL, and your URL should have meta tags to grab the information.

Comment: Thanks ! It worked like a charm. I had to modify some stuff but everything is working now. I can share to personal page and fan page with description, image and title.